# Get text from "How do you want to open this x file" -window?

Tags: c#, windows, autoit-c#-wrapper

My application monitors what pops up on screen but I'm struggling to get the details when Windows prompts for an unknown file associations like:

[image]

I've tried to get the details using Window Info tool, but soon as I click, the message disappears. I just want to get the text from the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

within "AutoIt v3 Window Info", goto "Options" and deactivate "Freeze" (remind the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl-Alt-F" to toggle this option. Then dobuleclick your file, move the mouse into the popup (as the screenshot in your question shows) and press "Ctrl-Alt-F" to "Freeze".

The "Summary" tab shows:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  
Class:  Shell_Flyout
Position:   760, 270
Size:   392, 330
Style:  0x96000000
ExStyle:    0x00000008
Handle: 0x00000000001C08DC

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  DirectUIHWND
Instance:   0
ClassnameNN:    DirectUIHWND0
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:DirectUIHWND; INSTANCE:0]
ID: 
Text:   
Position:   0, 0
Size:   392, 330
ControlClick Coords:    201, 172
Style:  0x56000000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x00000000001D0A52

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   961, 442
Cursor ID:  2
Color:  0xFFFFFF

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
```